# How to get Date from GPSDirectory?

Tags: java, geolocation

I am writing a java program which collect all the meta information(GPS : lat,long and date) from image (using library metadata-extractor-2.6.4)

```
 GpsDirectory gpsDir = (GpsDirectory) metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class);
 GpsDescriptor gpsDesc = new GpsDescriptor(gpsDir);
 System.out.println("Date : " + gpsDesc.getGpsTimeStampDescription());
```

I am getting date like "Date : 15:45:26 UTC". Is there any method which gives date in standard format like yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z?

I tried to use

```
  gpsDir.getDate(GpsDirectory.TAG_GPS_DATE_STAMP), but it returns null
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the metadata-extractor library's Javadoc?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use
>
> gpsDir.getDate(GpsDirectory.TAG_GPS_DATE_STAMP), but it returns null

In the [docs](http://metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Javadoc/com/drew/metadata/Directory.html#getDate%28int%29) for `getDate()`, it says: "Returns the specified tag's value as a java.util.Date. If the value is unset or cannot be converted, null is returned." Thus, `gpsDir.getDate(GpsDirectory.TAG_GPS_DATE_STAMP)` returns null probably because you haven't called this line:

```
gpsDir.setDate(GpsDirectory.TAG_GPS_DATE_STAMP, myDate);
```

> Is there any method which gives date in standard format like yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z?

Yes, just use `SimpleDateFormat`. I haven't tested this code but this should work:

```
final String OLD_FORMAT = "...";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy.MM.dd G at HH:mm:ss z";

String oldDateString = gpsDesc.getGpsTimeStampDescription();
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: thanks Barney, I want to collect the date which stored with image.